# Calculus derivates sin function

Tags: calculus

I know it seems easy but I can't make this derivative. 
$\sin(\frac{x}{2})$
If someone could answer it I would be so thankful

Comment: Apply the chain rule.

Comment: The next time you take calculus don't skip class so much.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sin'(x)=\cos(x)$$
$$\sin'(\frac{x}{2})=\sin'(u)=\cos(u) \cdot u'=
\cos(\frac{x}{2}) \cdot \frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

We have $$f(x)=\sin(\frac{x}{2})$$ then we get by the chain rule: $$f'(x)=\cos(\frac{x}{2})\cdot \frac{1}{2}$$